# Database charts .csv in custom tabs set into joomla template

Tags: database, joomla1.5, import-from-csv

I hired a firm to create database charts (updatable daily) in my existing joomla template. There are a few charts in each of 3 different tabs (modelled after ishares etf tables)
http://us.ishares.com/product_info/fund/overview/EWJ.htm

I just want 3 tabs...under each tab are a couple of database charts.

After weeks of work and complete agony...I'm now being told that it's not possible to do it. Is this true? They want to code it out of joomla. This creates a problem with the entire menu system as well as any CSS updates I might make.

I need to know if I'm being jerked around. Seems to be a simple thing to do...upload new .csv files daily.

I may also need to hire a new developer if so... help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd need more information on the tables you're trying to create, but my first sense is that you're either being jerked around, or they simply don't know how to code for Joomla as well as they thought. Nearly anything can be coded out for Joomla, if you know how to code out Components, Modules, and Plugins. Tabs with a couple tables on them should be child's play.

My company has written merchant gateway credit card processing apps, statistical analysis packages for imported table data, and custom art gallery management software, all for Joomla and all probably more complex than what you're indicating here. If it turns out you need to look for another developer, just let me know and I'll give you my business email.